# Function-like macro not accepting nested #define

Tags: c++, regex, macros, preprocessor

I am using macros to determine a variable's real type based on a pattern, and I am getting some weird macro errors that I do not understand:

```
a.cpp:15:4: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
                #define USING_INTEGER\
                 ^
a.cpp:15:11: error: unknown type name 'USING_INTEGER'
                #define USING_INTEGER\
                        ^
a.cpp:16:2: error: expected unqualified-id
        else if (matchRegex(DOUBLE_REGEX, val))\
        ^
3 errors generated.
```

Why is this happening? I have no idea, please provide some help if you know why.

```cpp
#include "example_3.cpp"
#include <regex>

std::string INT_REGEX = "^[-+]?\\d+$",
            DOUBLE_REGEX = "^[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d?$",
            BOOLEAN_REGEX = "^(true|false)$";

bool matchRegex(std::string pattern, std::string inputString) {
    std::regex expression(pattern);
    return std::regex_match(inputString, expression);
}

#define determineType(var)\
    if (matchRegex(INT_REGEX, val))\
        #define USING_INTEGER\
    else if (matchRegex(DOUBLE_REGEX, val))\
        #define USING_DOUBLE\
    else if (matchRegex(BOOLEAN_REGEX, val))\
        #define USING_BOOL\
    else\
        #define USING_RAW
```

Comment: You can't do that. The preprocessor doesn't let you define symbols in the middle of a macro.

Comment: Nested `#define` isn’t a thing; `#define` based on the results of C++ code doubly not. Why did you want to use a macro for this?

Comment: @Shawn damn that sucks, do you know of another way to make this possible then?

Comment: @Ry I'm using it to set flags about a variable's type to use later on - I'm making a transpiler for Scheme, and my Car function returns a string but I need a proper way to make a properly typed version of it - and this seemed suitable

Comment: Remember that the preprocessor effectively runs in *one* pass and one pass only. Additionally, you can't use C++ `if` code to conditionally `#define` something, you can only use `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` to manipulate them. It's important to note that C++ code does not actually run until the executable is launched and that is long, long after the compilation phase is complete.

Comment: What's wrong with using a proper function instead?

Comment: Types have to be applied and are checked at compile time. If you have multiple possible types which may occur at runtime, you have to prepare your source for all of them. `std::variant` is a possibility to "bundle" multiple types into a structure while always at most one of them is "active". Additionally, you may have an `enum` (containing enumerators for all of your possible types) to remember which type you identified in your reg. expression check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood the motivation of the OP's question the intention is:

- to parse text
- determine a certain type of input
- store the value in that type.

Types of variables have to be defined at compile time.
(That's one of the C++ language core concepts called [static type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking).
There is no chance to define a type of a variable at runtime.)

So, all the types which shall be supported have to defined in the source code at the same time.

As an input term may always have at most one of these types, the storage of the values may consider that.

In C, a [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) would come in mind but C++ provides something even better: [**std::variant**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

The variant will be defined with all supported types but an instance will always store a value of one of them. The type is chosen in the assignment depending of the right hand side.

An example to demonstrate that in action:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

// an error type
struct None { std::string text; };

// a value what can represent one of all supported types
typedef std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string, None> Value;

// reads a value from a text determining its type
Value readInput(const std::string &text)
{
  // check for int
  { std::istringstream in(text); int value;
    if (in >> value && in.tellg() == -1) {
      return Value(value);
    }
  }
  // check for floating point
  { std::istringstream in(text); double value;
    if (in >> value && in.tellg() == -1) {
      return Value(value);
    }
  }
  // check for bool
  if (text == "true") return Value(true);
  if (text == "false") return Value(false);
  // check for (quoted) string
  if (text.size() >= 2
    && ((text.front() == '"' && text.back() == '"')
    || (text.front() == '\'' && text.back() == '\''))) {
    return Value(text.substr(1, text.size() - 2));
  }
  // ERROR
  return Value(None{ text });
}

// prints the value (considering the current type)
void print(const Value &value)
{
  switch (value.index()) {
    case 0: std::cout << "bool: " << std::boolalpha << std::get<bool>(value); break;
    case 1: std::cout << "int: " << std::get<int>(value); break;
    case 2: std::cout << "double: " << std::get<double>(value); break;
    case 3: std::cout << "string: '" << std::get<std::string>(value) << '\''; break;
    case 4: std::cout << "ERROR! text: '" << std::get<None>(value).text << '\''; break;
    default: std::cout << "Value not initialized.";
  }
}

int main()
{
  const std::string tests[] = {
    "true", // bool
    "false", // bool
    "123", // int
    "123.17", // double
    "0", // int
    "0.0", // double
    "'text'", // string
    "''", // string
    "something that doesn't match any type" // ERROR
  };
  for (const std::string &test : tests) {
    std::cout << "Test \"" << test << "\"\n";
    const Value value = readInput(test);
    std::cout << "Got: ";
    print(value);
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Test "true"
Got: bool: true
Test "false"
Got: bool: false
Test "123"
Got: int: 123
Test "123.17"
Got: double: 123.17
Test "0"
Got: int: 0
Test "0.0"
Got: double: 0
Test "'text'"
Got: string: 'text'
Test "''"
Got: string: ''
Test "something that doesn't match any type"
Got: ERROR! text: 'something that doesn't match any type'
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b3ad24b94b8e8ef)